# Jquery.validate.js ignore parameter does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to ignore some of my fields to be validated. But its not working for me. Am i doing something wrong ?
I have tried this yet :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#myform").validate({
  ignore: ".ignore"
});
});
```

After this i am manipulating the ignore class with my code . As if i have many conditions like : 
 if A textbox is filled , B is not required.
 if B textbox is filled , A is not required.
But whenever i check

```
$("#myform").valid();
```

It always returns false even if A has class "ignore". Am i doing any mistake in it ?

But if i update this ignore in jquery.validate.js. It works! 
i dont want to update it there.

Thanks

Comment: Through the "ignore" what you are trying to ignore? Is it a specific control that you want to ignore during validation?

Comment: i want to ignore a validation on a specific control.

Comment: Show enough relevant code to reproduce the problem, including the HTML.  Otherwise, `ignore: ".ignore"` works perfectly fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/4ocywkr4/

Comment: @Sparky Yes, you are right its working . But i am also using the same code and thats not working. I will try replacing my jquery.validate.js on monday. There may be a problem in it.Or i will post some more code . Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of thing you could be doing wrong and there is not nearly enough code to tell.

Comment: How many times are you calling the `.validate()` method?  FYI:  it can only be called ***once*** to initialize the plugin.  You cannot call it repeatedly to dynamically change options, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Firstly i am calling the script , i dont know if this method is already called my MVC or not,i think yes. Then i am calling it in my document.ready function. After that i am checking if form is valid or not.

Comment: That's your problem if your framework is already calling `.validate()`.  Your subsequent call is ignored.  Try:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/